# Was I hacked using my android build number and baseband?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, malware

I had someone ask me for my Android  build and baseband number in an effort to help me root my Samsung 6S. Shortly afterwards my phone got really slow as if the CPU was processing large amounts of data. In an hour I checked my mail,  and a few were sent back to me that I was not sending. As if a malicious bulk mailing came from my phone,  and the old addresses of contacts that were invalid,  sent the mail back to me.

Is this unrelated malware or and actual attack perpetrated (theoretically)  by this person? Thsnks.

Comment: No.  Simply put, that is just information as to the build/version of the OS and baseband.  You weren't hacked from that information alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thousands of people likely have the same build and baseband as you do.  It's common to the ROM, not to your individual device.

To uniquely identify your device, they would need a globally unique identifier like IMEI.  However, those identifiers are also completely useless for hacking you — they don't provide any kind of magical access; they can only be used for identification.

Likely you either installed a bad app in the past, or used a malicious rooting tool, or are simply incorrect about what's happening here.

Comment: Probably all three of those last causes,  not necessarily in that order.